# Use Apache Camel for doing a fire and forget HTTP request

Tags: http, apache-camel, apache-httpclient-4.x, asynchttpclient

I would like to know if it is possible to do a HTTP POST Request fire and forget and don't wait until you get a response. I am not sure if I should using HTTP component or AHC, I guess AHC is more convenient for my scenario.

I am using Apache Camel 2.12.1 and Spring XML. If is possible, how can I achieve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choosing between the http4 and ahc Camel components is not a matter of asynchronism but of performance under heavy load. Said differently, if your request rate is small or medium, http4 component is enough.

There are several ways of achieving "request fire and forget" whatever the target component is:

- Use ProducerTemplate#asyncSend to create a request-only exchange http://camel.apache.org/async.html
- Use a SEDA component with waitForTaskToComplete set to Never http://camel.apache.org/seda.html

In both cases, the request will be executed in separate thread, so the caller won't wait.

Comment: I ended up using Async and AHC because I need to handle heavy load. Thanks for the options.